# Possible to do quicksort without splitting into separate lists?

Tags: sorting

In many quicksort algorithms, the programming involves placing the elements from each array into three groups:(`less`, `pivot`, `more`), and sometimes placing the groups back together. What if I do not want to use this? Is there a simpler approach to sorting a list with quicksort manually?

Basically, I plan to keep the array as one, and swap all the elements based on a partition (for example, given a list `x` and pivot `r`, we could have the reference lists of `[0:r]` and `[r:len(x)]`. However, as the sorting continues, how do I continue referencing each smaller "subarray"?

So this is my code, but I'm not sure how to continue from here:

```
x = [4,7,4,2,4,6,5]
#r is pivot POSITION
r = len(x)-1
i = -1
for a in range(0,r+1):
    if x[a] <= x[r]:
        i+=1
        x[i], x[a] = x[a], x[i]
```

Comment: The entire idea of quick sort is to 'Divide & Conquer' , We can do it without physically splitting the group. But like I said, the whole idea of quick sort is to dividing the list & manipulate.

Comment: What you described in your edit sounds like it should work. Are you having a specific problem implementing it?

Comment: Yes, I have my code up there

Comment: And your specific problem is ...?

Comment: Sorry, never mind, I have fixed the issue already.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can implement quicksort purely by swapping the locations of items in a list, rather than actually creating new lists.

But unless this is some sort of homework assignment, the best option is generally to use python's built-in sort() function, which automatically uses quicksort where appropriate.

Comment: Yes, this is what I have been trying to do, but I face problems when referencing different parts of the program. And I want to use strictly quicksort only.

Comment: Could you be more specific about what you've tried and what went wrong? Code and error messages can be really helpful in zeroing in on what exactly you need help with.

Answer (score 0):

There's something not right in here. You need to have two definitions, one for the partition and one for the quicksort process itself. The quicksort will then need to have some sort of loop, so that it will continue applying the partition to subarrays of the array. Go and check the Wikipedia [article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort#Algorithm)  to understand how this works.

Comment: Thanks, actually I have already found out how to do it here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32421579/python-quicksort-program-in-place